# Unity 3D RMB / Flythrough in Blender

Tags: unity, shortcut

When I hold down the right mouse button in Unity 3D, I can rotate around the current view. I THINK (this may be wrong however) that this is called "Flythrough".

I haven't found the name of this function in Blender so I couldn't change the "shortcut" for it.

I wanted Blender to navigate like Unity.

How could I make the right mouse button in Blender act like the right mouse button in Unity?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Github project located here:

https://github.com/niusounds/Blender-Keyconfig

I followed the instructions given on that page, and I had an 1:1 navigation in Blender as in Unity.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Unity for years but I believe this is what you are referring to.

It's here in 'User Preferences'(CTRL+ALT+U) -> 'Input' :

[image]

Do this:
[image]

Then WASD for movement forward, left, back, right and Q & E for up and down. Shift will make movement faster and ALT slower.

You will have to click the Left Mouse Button to accept the movement and not return to starting point.

Hope that does the trick for you. But the tmighty's answer looks more complete in terms of mirroring Unity navigation, if that is what you are after.

Comment: Scroll up/down in fly mode will increase the speed permanently, I important a big world once and wondered why the fly didn't work... it just was so miniscule, that not even "shift" made it any better